# Can't Use Puppeteer -- Error: Failed to launch chrome

Tags: node.js, gitlab-ci, puppeteer

This is the error I get. This occurs when the test code is run in the Gitlab CI.

However, it works fine locally. Someone please help?

```
2036 $ npm test
```

> 2037 > 10_auth@1.1.3 test /builds/brhanuh/domestic-repair
>
> 2038 > jest --coverage 'unitTests/'
>
> 2039 Error: Failed to launch chrome!
>
> 2040
>   /builds/brhanuh/domestic-repair/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-686378/chrome-linux/chrome:
>   error while loading shared libraries: libX11-xcb.so.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Welcome to SO! What about posting your code? You will get a lot of hypothesis with your question

Answer (score 38):

Install the missing packages using

```
sudo apt install -y gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
```

Credits to @coldner on [the puppetteer issue tracker](https://github.com/Googlechrome/puppeteer/issues/290) for assembling the required pkgs.

If you encounter `E: Unable to locate package` errors, run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: That worked for me on Google Cloud instance (running Debian). Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is working for my bitbucket as well. Cheer. You are the best!

Answer (score 11):

I just wanted to add to @mohammad's answer, that now Puppetteer now has [an official troublshooting guide](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md) that helps you determine what to install.

Also, they recommend running the following command to tell which [particular packages need installing on *nix systems](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-unix):

```
ldd chrome | grep not
```

Or, if you have Chrome installed via Puppetteer via NPM like me:

```
ldd ./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-756035/chrome-linux/chrome | grep not
```

Then, I was able to see what libraries were still missing, and install accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

For those that are still having this problem, you can try this.

sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgbm1 libgcc1 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 lsb-release wget xdg-utils

Answer (score 1):

you need to install required dependencies

here

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

under `Chrome headless doesn't launch on UNIX` you can find

```
Debian (e.g. Ubuntu) Dependencies
CentOS Dependencies
```